# What is the best way to store text files remotely?

Tags: mysql, database, text

I am building a "document storage" system for storing text files on my server. I was wondering if anybody has any recommendations or best practices on the best way to store text files remotely.

The system will be user-based, each user can upload multiple text files. I want the text files to be stored in some fashion which is easy to perform a full-text search.

The server I am using is a standard web server, with a multitude of scripting languages, and MySQL database support.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would store them in the database and using the full text search in MySQL.
Of course you have to have at least MySQL 3.23.23 installed (which is when support for full-text searching was added.).

Comment: Are there any concerns with file size with this method?

Comment: Not what Im familiar with. 
Of course the full text search in mysql has its limits, read more here:  http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/12809.html where they talk a